# Как на Java параллельно сложить два массива?

Tags: java, массивы, распараллеливание

Например, есть два огромных (длина 2-3 млн.) массива `float[]` или `double[]` без разницы. Нужно их очень быстро сложить. Как это сделать? Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки для этого?

Comment: На каком языке складываем?

Comment: На Java. В теме написано.

Comment: если нужно быстро сложить, то имеет смысл использовать sse и складывать по 4 или 8 элементов одновременно. Но как с ним в Java - не знаю.

Comment: я работал с sse на с++, но вот как в java тоже незнаю пока

Comment: я думаю, нужно поступить классическим способом - просто написать нативный код и с java через jni обращаться. Если код недоступен - использовать java версию. Но перед этим хорошо потестить, может выигрыш будет пара процентов.

Comment: как-то геморно. сборка через maven делается. код на git'e. где хранить сишный код? отдельную репу надо делать. сборку как делать? деплоить как... куча проблем появляется. хорошо бы найти какую-нибудь либу и просто заюзать ее.

Comment: и что, что код на git'е? Это вообще никак не мешает. И что, что сборка через maven? ему что, компилировать?

Я бы для начала потестировал. если прирост будет существенным, тогда уже задавался вопросом, куда выкинуть мавен, если он не сможет собрать.

Comment: а через System.arraycopy будет слишком долго ?

Comment: сложить имеется ввиду не объединить, а арифметически сложить. так что arraycopy не подходит:
public static void arraycopy(Object source, int sourcePosition, 
 Object destination, int destinationPosition, int numberOfElements)

Comment: Я бы в потоках (по числу ядер) попробовал. Каждый поток суммирует свой диапазон индексов массивов.

Вопрос тут в том, как платформонезависимо на Java определить количество ядер.

Comment: обычно используют http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors%28%29

Comment: На .NET вам помог бы PLINQ, который сам знает о количестве процессоров/ядер. Знатоки, есть аналоги на Java?

Comment: @VladD, вот же @IronVbif точно указал `Runtime.availableProcessors();`

Кстати, Вам из "исследований" нотификации об изменениях и новых комментариях приходят?

Comment: кажется у вас открытая область для разработки новой библиотеки :D

Comment: @Flyte, вы написали:

> Нужно их очень быстро сложить

У вас есть реальный код, в котором, в процесе рефакторинга, вы обнаружили, что сложение является узким местом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я про 8 Java и LambdaJ написал скорее для общего ознакомления и для ответа на коммент про аналоги LINQ.

Если отвечать в рамках вопроса, то ни *LINQ*, ни *Java 8* и ни *LambdaJ* не является быстрым решением вопрооса сложения (с точки зрения производительности). Сложение слишком простая операция и накладные расходы на вского рода вкусности, вроде функционального стиля, будут слишком велики. Согласно докам по LambdaJ она в два раза медленее в среднем чем просто циклы. (В некоторых местах доходит до 4х раз).
Новая Java все еще не в релизе, и пользоваться ей в продакшене не стоит.

Остается только ручная многопоточность (мне кажется что 2-3 миллиона это не такие уж и огромные данные для операции сложения). На своем дряхленьком нетбуке я смог ускоритсья на двух тредах. Выложил код на [гитхаб](https://github.com/Vbif/ArraySum), надеюсь ктонить попробует и выложит информацию с нормального железа.

Насчет использования с++ и SSE, следующий код:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
```

Компилится в SSE инструкции JIT'ом. Насколько будет выйгрыш, если вручную написать на SSE - не знаю. Возможно не стоит заморачиваться с нативным кодом.

Comment: Не могу назвать железо нормальным, да и не совсем понял что значит FourSum, тем не менее:

SimplySum 12.355556 ms

FourSum 20.609053 ms

TwoThreadSum 9.856299 ms

#####AMD A10-4600M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4

Answer (score 1):

Это ответ не по теме, но возможно, другим участникам сайта он пригодится в будущем.

В **.NET** PLINQ [умеет самостоятельно](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819128.aspx) разбить задание на нужное количество потоков (определяемое количеством процессоров/ядер на хосте) и выполнить операцию параллельно по частям.

```
int length = Math.Min(arr1.Length, arr2.Length);
double[] results = 
      ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, length).AsOrdered()
        .Select(index => arr1[index] + arr2[index])
        .ToArray();
```

---

Update: Как верно заметил [[@IronVbif](/users/443/ironvbif)](/users/443/ironvbif), «наивный» PLINQ медленнее цикла, выполненного вручную. Однако на этот случай у .NET есть [специальная перегрузка](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853.aspx):

```
int length = Math.Min(arr1.Length, arr2.Length);
double[] results = new double[length];
var rangePartitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, length);
Parallel.ForEach(rangePartitioner, (range, loopState) =>
    {
        for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
            result[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
    });
```

(выполняется существенно быстрее, чем простое сложение).

Comment: @VladD В 8 джаве будет (точнее уже есть) аналог LINQ и PLINQ. Для <=7 есть LambdaJ, но сам ей не пользовался. Вообще JIT сам может генерировать SSE инструкции, надо наверно цикл развернуть на 4 сложения за раз. А потом с потоками побаловаться.

Comment: @Barmaley: Это не java, это .NET :-(

Comment: @VladD, значит "исследования" совсем в бета-фазе, раз никому нотификаций нет. 

Просто хочу сегодня-завтра (если опять ничего на работе не свалится) дополнить нашу тему там.

Comment: @IronVbif: Напишете пример кода на Java 8 отдельным ответом? Если ещё и добавите пример параллелизации с LambdaJ, будет вообще супер.

Comment: @downvoter: объясните минус?